# Spring Boot GemFire Pivotal Cloud Cache @EnableClusterAware and ClientCacheRegionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

Im trying to connect to *Pivotal Cloud Cache* server Regions.

I'm using `@EnableClusterAware` and trying to configure the client Regions via `ClientRegionFactoryBean` as below:

```java
@Bean("clientRegion")
ClientRegionFactoryBean someClientRegion(GemFireCache gemfire) {
   // ...
}
```

Either `GemFireCache` or `ClientCache` beans are not available with the annotation `@EnableClusterAware`. It's available only with `@ClientCacheApplication`.

Is there any annotations that needs to be used in conjunction with `@EnableClusterAware` so that `GemFireCache` gets injected?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When *Spring Boot for Apache Geode*, or alternatively GemFire, (SBDG) is on the classpath of your Spring Boot application (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#maven-gradle)), then SBDG *auto-configuration* will automatically create and configure a `ClientCache` instance for you (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-clientcache-applications)).

> TIP: You can also review the **Getting Stated** Sample [Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html) and [Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/tree/1.6.4/spring-geode-samples/intro/getting-started) to see this behavior in action, for yourself.  The Guide also talks about the use of the `@EnableClusterAware` annotation, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html#spring-geode-samples-getting-started-build-app-configuration-cluster).

The `@EnableClusterAware` annotation is simply a development-time, SBDG annotation that enables you to switch between environments (e.g. local vs. managed, such as when pushing your Spring Boot application up to run in PCF,  connected to PCC, and then testing locally in your IDE) without having to change any configuration (hence the [goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#introduction-goals)).

The `@EnableClusterAware` annotation does not create any GemFire/Geode cache instances for you.  Only SBDG's *auto-configuration*, or declaring an explicit SDG annotation (e.g. `@ClientCacheApplication`) will do that for you.  Still, when using SBDG *auto-configuration*, you do not need an explicit SDG cache application annotation, like `@ClientCacheApplication`, since SBDG auto-configuration (again) creates and configures a `ClientCache` instance by default.

> TIP: See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative-annotations-productivity-enableclusteraware) on the `@EnableClusterAware` annotation for more details.

If `ClientCache` is not provided (*auto-configured*), then you are not:

1. Using SBDG, or rather do not have SBDG on the Spring Boot application classpath (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.6.4/spring-geode-samples/intro/getting-started/pom.xml#L27-L30))
2. Have not [bootstrapped](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.6.4/spring-geode-samples/intro/getting-started/src/main/java/example/app/crm/CrmApplication.java#L38) or [configured](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.6.4/spring-geode-samples/intro/getting-started/src/main/java/example/app/crm/CrmApplication.java#L42) and ran your Spring application with Spring Boot
3. Your Spring Boot application configuration is incorrect
4. You have explicitly [disabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-disabling) or [overrode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-overriding) the SBDG auto-configuration
5. Etc.

One or more of these have to be true.

Comment: Also, FTR, there is nothing wrong with your client Region bean definition.  That looks fine.